# How many rows affected with MySQL query using Excel VBA ADODB

Tags: mysql, excel, adodb, vba

I'm sending SQL queries from Excel VBA to MySQL, using ADODB. When sending queries for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE, I would like to be able to return the number of rows affected in the DB, from my VBA function. How can I obtain the number of records affected post SQL execution?

Here's a sample code from a DELETE function:

```
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mycol>5;"

    ConnectDB
    rs.Open strSQL, ConnDB
```